# Sum of K connected nodes binary tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, dynamic-programming

I want to find maximum sum of `K` connected nodes in a binary tree. I thought of doing this through memorizing, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Think about how the problem breaks down. A connected subgraph of a binary tree is itself a tree. In particular, there is a root of the the subgraph, and the children of the root are also trees.

So, consider the following related problem. Given the binary tree and a particular node `X`, what is the maximum sum of a subtree rooted at `X`, where the subtree has `N` nodes?

If you could answer that question for `N=1` through `N=i`, then you can answer the same question for `N=i+1` by fixing the node `X`, choosing `j` nodes from `X`'s left child, and `i-j` nodes from `X`'s right child, for some choice of `0<=j<=i`. This illustrates the "optimal subproblem" property required for dynamic programming.